# How to find whether setcap is supported in Linux

Tags: linux, kernel

I have a libpcap based application. Now, to allow non-root users to use my app, during installation , i use setcap

```
setcap cap_net_raw=ep /bin/myapp
```

But, in case the Linux Distro on which i install my app does not support Linux Capabilities, i want to use setuid().
  Now, is their any way by which we can figure out whether Linux Capabilities and setuid() are supported for current Linux Distro or not.
  Besides, is there any link, where all Linux Distros having Linux Capabilities support are displayed.

Comment: I thought capabilities was a thing of Linux(?)

Comment: @WikiWitz It is a thing of Linux, but some custom kernels don't come with Linux Capabilities support.

Comment: @WikiWitz Some older filesystems don't have a place to store capabilities, too.

Comment: Do we have an answer to the actual question, ie : "how to check either linux has a given capability " ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the current used kernel config

```
# cat /proc/config.gz | gunzip | grep CAPABILITY                                                                   
CONFIG_CCSECURITY_CAPABILITY=y
```

This indicate that `CONFIG_CCSECURITY_CAPABILITY` is used and thus capabilities are enabled.

Also if `libcap-utils` are installed `/sbin/capsh --print` can be used to check the availability of the capability.